# How to display both text title and loading icon on the middle navigation?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

[image]

If user clicks the icon, refresh starts. I found this https://github.com/Just-/UINavigationItem-Loading library, but it can't display both text title and loading icon on the middle navigation.

Like this photo:

Answer (score 5):

Navigation item has property named `"titleView"`.
Crete your view as you wish with label and reloadButton and then assign titleView this view:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [self getCustomView];
```

Comment: Is there any library easy to use?

Comment: It can't be easier than this. I understood you have only label + button.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar` is kind of `UIView`, You can do `addSubView:` in that. So add  `UILabel` & `UIActivityIndicator`.

Let me know if you need anymore clarification.

Refer this [link](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/18/adding-an-activity-indicator-to-navigation-bar/) for code